# Python PIL 3D projection

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to place an image into perspective using Python PIL. The four points of the image in 2D are transformed into 3D space. Then four new points in these space are assigned. How can I transform this in an image using `image.transform` from the PIL module?

For example the points show be transformed from points 1 to points 2.

Points 1: `(0,0,1), (1,0,1), (0,1,1), (1,1,1)`

Points 2: `(0,0,1), (1,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,1,0)`